# pandas_datareader throws Error 404

Tags: pandas-datareader

My code to get stock data from pandas_datareader was working properly before yesterday but now it gives an error which is given below. Please suggest how resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

> Error: File "C:...\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py",
>   line 130, in _dl_mult_symbols resp.status_code, resp.reason))
>
> Exception: Request Error!: 404 : Not Found

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue so I used quand1

```
import quand1
df = quand1.get("WIKI/AAPL", start_date=startDate, end_date=endDate)
print(df)
```

Similarly, place whichever ticker you want where 'AAPL' is

Comment: Thanks but why pandas_datareader is not working. Many of tickers in quandl don't have most recent data as in pandas_datareader.